# iis url rewrite not redirecting from default site to defaultsite/app

Tags: iis

I am having trouble wrestling url rewrite and need to handle this in IIS. What I need is to ensure that all traffic that hits the server is redirected to https://server/app. I can handle this using a standard http to https rewrite which seems to work fine redirecting http://server to https://server/app but it doesn't work if someone hits https://server.

Here's my standard rewrite:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="http to https" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/app" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Because you wrote a rule that only performs redirection when HTTPS is off. To make a proper rule for your true goal, you should learn how to write a regular expression to match "URL does not start with `app/`".

Comment: You can try this configure: `<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />`, If it still doesn't work, you can create another rule to redirect `https://server`.